# HttpWebRequest SSL Authorization form

Tags: ssl, https, httpwebrequest

I've never tried before, but now I really need to get through authorization on Sprint's site (www.sprint.com).

Could you guys help me to understand how this actually works?

I'm trying to do like this, but obviously I'm missing something. Either something about cookies 
or ssl or other stuff, I don't know.

```
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
                                                "https://sso.sprintpcs.com/sso/Login.do");
  CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
  webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
  webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
                          chromeframe; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; 
                          .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
  webRequest.Accept = "image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, 
                       image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-shockwave-flash,
                       application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, */*";

  webRequest.Method = "POST";
  webRequest.Host = "manage.sprintpcs.com";

  string strUserId = "kindauser";
  string strPass = "kindapass";

  ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
  string postData = "userid=" + strUserId + "&password=" 
                    + strPass + "&userExperince=USC allowlogin=false";

  byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
  Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
  requestStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);

  HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: userExperince looks like a typo

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following - and this applies to all cases where you want to interact wit a website.

1) get firefox, along with firebug extension.
2) clear the firefox content and cookie cache
3) use firefox to do the scenario - logging into the website, for eg.
4) At this point, firebug shows you the exact sequence of requests sent along withh the cookie headers, etc.

5) Now try to replicate this using code.